# GWTP + MGWT - Errors in 'jar:file:mgwt-1.1.1.jar!/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/theme/MGWTThemeBaseThemeStandardImpl.java'

Tags: gwt, gwtp, mgwt

I am trying to write the build.xml for a GWTP+MGWT project for mobile, desktop & tablet.

```
    <javac srcdir="${apt_generated}" destdir="${out.classes.folder}" includeantruntime="true" source="1.6" target="1.6" nowarn="false" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" >
        <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
         <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
    </javac>
    <javac srcdir="${in.src.folder}" fork="true"   memoryinitialsize="512m" memorymaximumsize="1024m"  includes="**" encoding="utf-8" destdir="${out.classes.folder}" source="1.6" target="1.6" nowarn="false" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="true">
        <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
         <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
    </javac>    
    <copy todir="${out.classes.folder}">
        <fileset dir="${in.src.folder}" includes="**/*.class" />
    </copy>
    <delete dir="${in.src.folder}" includes="**/*.class" failonerror="false" />
```

The application runs fine in dev mode but i see the following error when i do a "ant gwtc"-

```
gwtc:
     [java] Compiling module com.company.proj.fe.TestApp
     [java]    Validating newly compiled units
     [java]       Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
     [java] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.

     [java]    [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/workspace/testapp/war/WEB-INF/lib/
mgwt-1.1.1.jar!/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/theme/
MGWTThemeBaseThemeStandardImpl.java'
     [java]       [ERROR]  Internal compiler error
     [java] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
     [java]     at java.lang.String.toCharArray(String.java:2725)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$CompilationUnitAdapter.getContents(AbstractCompiler.java:105)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9485)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9457)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:8102)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:322)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:131)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getType(LookupEnvironment.java:1090)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.resolveType(JdtCompiler.java:438)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.resolvePossiblyNestedType(AbstractCompiler.java:292)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$500(AbstractCompiler.java:139)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.resolvePossiblyNestedType(AbstractCompiler.java:625)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.checkRebindResultInstantiable(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:130)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:118)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:254)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:173)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:288)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:139)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:588)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:97)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:52)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:569)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
```

I added fork="true" memoryinitialsize="512m" memorymaximumsize="1024m". but these do not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced some problems compiling GWT applications, if the JRE has to few memory.

Try to increase the memory of your ant process.

One of my GWT applications is only compilable within a 64 bit JVM.

I compile my applications with 4g RAM and in a 64bit JVM.